# Salesforce Events Vs Data Extensions as a Entry source in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have two systems in place i.e. Salesforce and Marketing cloud where Salesforce has all the master data sharing with MC through connector. 
Now while building the journeys, I am thinking to use the salesforce event instead of creating the custom DE and pushing the data into them through SQL/Automations. I have gone through the big limitation of bulk data updating in salesforce can fail to push the data through salesforce events but we are ok with this. 
I want to know the experience of using salesforce events instead of data extension and its benefits or any drawback that should be taken care off. Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to Platform Events, Change Data Capture Events or the Events object record?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I am referring here Salesforce data as entry event.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, use Salesforce Entry Source (either Data or Campaign) only for single emails, like Welcome emails, satisfaction survey, etc. For bulk email sends, like newsletters, use a Data Extension, or even better - use Automation Studio with Salesforce import activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all things with Salesforce Marketing Cloud, using Salesforce Event generally works "well enough". A primary consideration when using events vs Automations in general is the timeliness of the data: events will trigger faster whereas the automations are generally on the hour or less frequent. If your needs are a fast response (eg. a journey email on entry), then this is a good path.

The issue you will likely run into is the eventual potential discovery that not all records are making it through and you'll find yourself likely using a SQL activity to attempt to audit the data source and actual events.

So in general, its a feature, it generally works well, particularly if timeliness matters, but it's also not flawless. If you build an automation to audit the results ahead of time, you're in great shape.